# Send a FCM notification when updates are made in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Guys I'm pushing FCM notification to my android app using PHP script which works fine.

What I'm trying to achieve is when a row is inserted to MySQL database table then I want to push the notification.I tried using triggers so when a row is inserted to a table I execute my php script to push a notification, but that wasn't a good way of doing it.

so is there a way to connect Firebase to MySQL or to detect those updates using Firebase (row inserted) and then push a notification if condition is approved(row inserted).

so guys hope you get the idea sorry for my bad enlish.if you have any suggestions to achieve this with a better way I'm listening.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You control the script that inserts into the database right? Why not just add to that script and have it run a function that triggers the FCM?

Comment: nah that's the problem I don't control the script that inserts into the database I'm working on a mobile app based on an open source software

Comment: pls tell us what can you know there is/are data inserted if you do not have control over the script ? (say do you have control over the mysql?)

Comment: yes I do Have full access to the databse